# Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version. - Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

After the writer class ends. The error occurs in spring batch execution.(large data)

chunkorientedTasklet:[inputs not busy, ended:false]
taskletstep : Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.
Rollingback with transactions in unknown state

Stack trace:

```
2014-11-07 14:44:42,220 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter] - <Writing to flat file with 33 items.>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,221 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter] - <Writing to flat file with 33 items.>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,221 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter] - <Writing to flat file with 33 items.>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,221 INFO [Write.DocumentRequestWriter] - <DocumentRequestWriterEND- Completed Class execution>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,221 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet] - <Inputs not busy, ended: false>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,222 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep] - <Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=1, written=1, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,225 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep] - <Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=1, version=1, name=step1, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=1, filterCount=0, writeCount=1 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,231 INFO [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep] - <Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,231 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep] - <Rolling back with transaction in unknown state>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,232 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Handling exception: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException, caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,232 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Handling fatal exception explicitly (rethrowing first of 1): org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,233 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] - <Encountered an error executing the step>
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at uk.co.pruhealth.heal.docgen.main.DocumentGenerationMain.main(DocumentGenerationMain.java:88)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:665)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3901)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3907)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:301)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:200)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:267)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:210)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:312)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:75)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:610)
    ... 26 more
2014-11-07 14:44:42,272 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] - <Encountered an error saving batch meta data. This job is now in an unknown state and should not be restarted.>
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=1 with wrong version (1), where current version is 2
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao.updateStepExecution(MapStepExecutionDao.java:98)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:244)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at uk.co.pruhealth.heal.docgen.main.DocumentGenerationMain.main(DocumentGenerationMain.java:88)
2014-11-07 14:44:42,273 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] - <Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=1, version=1, name=step1, status=UNKNOWN, exitStatus=UNKNOWN, readCount=1, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=1>
2014-11-07 14:44:42,278 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob] - <Encountered interruption executing job>
org.springframework.batch.core.JobInterruptedException: Step requested termination: StepExecution: id=1, version=1, name=step1, status=UNKNOWN, exitStatus=UNKNOWN, readCount=1, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=1, exitDescription=org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at uk.co.pruhealth.heal.docgen.main.DocumentGenerationMain.main(DocumentGenerationMain.java:88)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:665)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3901)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3907)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:301)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:200)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:267)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:210)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:312)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:75)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:610)
    ... 26 more

    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
```

Comment: Can you please paste the full stack trace?

Comment: Updated the Stack trace . Please help me in this.. 
May i know the root cause for this..

I am processing about 300 records and able to get the csv file generated. But its not working for 3000 records.

I guess its due to the following error ?? i am not sure ..,

2014-11-07 14:44:42,221 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet] - <Inputs not busy, ended: false>

Comment: That exception means that the database server reset the connection in the middle of a transaction (a no-no).  You'll want to take a look at your connection pool settings as well as if there is a firewall that is killing your connection.

Comment: I am hitting the Db and taking values before 2 seconds. It is working perfectly. Why after 2 second it fails. What type of configuration change should i make

Comment: Hi  Michael Minella- For me a single chunk in spring batch takes more time to execute. How to increase the time..

Comment: Without seeing how you're datasource is configured, that depends.  Are you using a keep alive query?  Also, is there a firewall between the server this is running on and the database?  If so, it may be cutting the connection.